# image not showing from internet using Image.network

Tags: flutter, assets

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          title: Text("I AM RICH"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:Image(
            image: NetworkImage('https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'),
          ),
      ),
    ),
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Could it be a CORS issue?

Answer (score 38):

In debug mode service extension and multiple permissions are enabled by default(in flutter)

as you are in release mode you have to add internet permission in androidmanifest.xml manually.( Just like you add it in native development)

navigate to android-> app-> src-> main-> AndroidManifest.xml and add this line outside of application scope.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: This solved my problem since I published my app and it didn't work, Flutter should have automatically added it.

Comment: Thank you. This happened to me all the time when I was working with Android. This is still happening to me years later now when I'm working with Flutter. Some things never change :)

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me today and i figured that my emulator was not connected to the internet.if you are facing this issue make sure your device you are using is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 4):

Even I was facing the same problem until I checked that my device was not connected to the Internet and later turned it On the NetworkImage loaded the image from the URL string passed

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `network` constructor. Please change this:

```
Image(
  image: NetworkImage('https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'),
)
```

to this:

```
Image.network('https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use in `Container` in your `body` like this and wrap your `Container` with `Center` Widget**

```
Container(
            height: 90,
            width: 90,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(   
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage("https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"),
                //whatever image you can put here
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
           ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your emulator is able to access internet first. Try loading any url in Google Chrome inside emulator. If not, add the dns address 8.8.8.8 to your network settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below line in main/Manifest file. 
***android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"***

You can get more detail by implementing ***errorBuilder*** listener in Image.network widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine, to resolve this shutdown android studio & Emulator and restart it again.
 It works for me, and it keeps happening to me, I guess its because it couldn't load the photo

```
CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/218-2189254_free-online-avatars-kid-characters-family-vector-for.png'));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504

Answer (score 0):

Also check if your phone connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

n debug mode service extension and multiple permissions are enabled by default(in flutter)

as you are in release mode you have to add internet permission in androidmanifest.xml manually.( Just like you add it in native development)

navigate to android-> app-> src-> main-> AndroidManifest.xml and add this line outside of application scope.

Comment: you forgot to add the line that we should add to AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that you do not put a space at the beginning of the image link

Comment: Please check if your link is valid or not for android you have to give internet permission in the androidmanifest file.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble displaying an image from the internet using the `Image.network` widget in Flutter, there are a few potential solutions you can try:

1. **Check the image URL:** Ensure that the URL you are providing to `Image.network` is correct and accessible. You can try opening the URL directly in a web browser to verify if the image loads successfully.
2. **Verify internet connectivity:** Make sure you have an active internet connection on the device or emulator where you're running your Flutter app. Check if you can access other websites or resources on the internet.
3. **Handle potential errors:** Wrap the `Image.network` widget with an `ErrorWidget` to handle any errors that might occur during image loading. This way, you can display a fallback widget or an error message instead of a blank image. For example:

```dart
Image.network(
  imageUrl,
  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
    return Text('Failed to load image');
  },
),
```

4. **Enable network permissions:** If you're testing your app on an Android device or emulator, ensure that the necessary network permissions are added to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Open the file located at `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure the following permission is present inside the `<manifest>` tag:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

5. **Check for proxy or firewall restrictions:** If you're working in an environment with proxy settings or firewalls, ensure that they do not block the network requests made by your Flutter app. Consult with your network administrator to verify if there are any restrictions in place.
6. **Wrap with a SingleChildScrollView or ListView:** If the `Image.network` widget is inside a container with a fixed size, such as a `Column` or `Row`, the image might not be displayed due to size constraints. Wrap the `Image.network` widget with a `SingleChildScrollView` or `ListView` to allow the widget to expand and show the image. For example:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Image.network(imageUrl),
)
```

These are some common solutions that can help resolve issues with images not displaying from the internet using `Image.network` in Flutter. Make sure to verify the image URL, check network connectivity, handle errors, and ensure proper permissions are set as needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: How to Cold Boot]
Cold Boot Now option Fixed My Issue and All Images Displayed!
Ofcourse make sure you have this code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```